# goland on windows not recognizing imports and throw error

Tags: go, goland

i have enabled the go modules integration according to this docs .
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/create-a-project-with-go-modules-integration.html#enable-go-modules-in-a-project
but yet again as you can see in image below . goland keep throwing error on some code i have
[image]

as you can see in image i have that execlise package but it keep giving error . not only that i have some error on other files
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens sometimes with IDEs, from my experience it may happen because of at least three reasons.

**first:** the differences between package versions in your go.sum, you should empty the go.sum and run `go mod tidy command`.

**Second:** the version you’re using is older or newer than what you’re expecting, so the package does not support these methods or didn’t include them. so you should set the exact version of the package. (I suggest you read the documentation of the package in this case)

**Third:** your IDE has got some problems with the caches.  for solving this: you should click on `file -> invalidate caches` to rebuild your IDE caches.